# read all csv files in a directory using `purrr:map()`

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I would like to read in all of the *.csv files in a directory using `purrr::map`, and I just wanted to ask if there's a better way than what I'm doing, particularly if it's from the tidyverse or easier to read.

In particular, would you use `file.path()`? Is there a simpler way, or an easier to read way?

```
library(tidyverse)

csv_filenames <- list.files(path = "raw_data/")
dfs <- map(csv_filenames, ~read_csv(file.path("raw_data/", .)))
df <- bind_rows(dfs)
```

Comment: looks pretty simple to me, if all the `.csv` files have the same column structure, you can just use `map_df()` to get the `data.frame` output

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have `list.files` return full paths, which can be fed directly to map. Combined with the `map_df` suggestion in the comments, I would do:

```
df <- list.files( path="raw_data", full.names=TRUE ) %>% 
  map_dfr( read_csv )     # _dfr to be explicit about *row* binding
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this `base R` solution:

```
files <- list.files(path = "raw_data/",pattern='.csv')
#Data frame
DF <- do.call('rbind',lapply(files,read.csv))
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I also need to use `file.path()` to point the `lapply` towards the path "raw_data/"?

Comment: @JeremyK. I believe is not necessary because `.csv` files were identified. Let me know if you have troubles!