# How to write a for loop to read csv files and store them into a new dataframe with R studio

Tags: r

R Beginners here

I have a folder contains 150 csv files, each file name is "student1" "student2"....

Each files has 2 columns with Courses and Score

I want to run a for loop for this and store all of the data into a new dataframe.

so far I have :

```
data_1 = dir(path_cwd.full.names = TRUE, pattern = "csv$")

for(i in data_1)
{
b = read.csv(i,sep = ", " header = TRUE)

}
```

Please help me and explain it to me!

Much thanks

Comment: Some approaches here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62598787/read-all-csv-files-in-a-directory-using-purrrmap

Answer (score 0):

You can use lapply here. It is basically the same as for loop but you will more control over the operation. Here we will use lapply to get each file and then using do.call we will bind all data frames into one dataframe. The point is that you should make sure all csv files have the same number of columns and their names and order of columns are matched. Else, you may need to do more steps in between.

```
data_1 = dir(path_cwd.full.names = TRUE, pattern = "csv$"

final_df <- lapply(data_1, function(i){
b = read.csv(i,sep = ", " header = TRUE)
}) %>% do.call(what = rbind)
```